# Does "Lycoris" have a confirmed origin as a derivation of some Greek word meaning Twilight?

Tags: greek-to-english-translation

[Got told](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/74036/does-lycoris-have-a-confirmed-origin-as-a-derivation-of-some-greek-word-meaning?noredirect=1#comment239464_74036) that this isn't History, but does fit here, even though this is the "Latin" Stack not the "Greek" Stack?

---

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Lycoris&diff=77842370&oldid=77842213) said that "Lycoris" means "Twilight" since 2006.

And the [etymology-of-names Wiki](https://etymology-of-names.fandom.com/wiki/Lycoris?action=history) starting from 2014 mentions a supposition of how it could be related:

> Lycoris was possibly used for the first time by Cornelius Gallus as a pseudonym for Cytheris. There is a genus of plants called Lycoris and it is possibly related to the Greek words lykophos, lykauges or lykos, which mean "twilight", "morning twilight, dawn", and "wolf" respectively.

Do we have anything more solid on the meaning of "Lycoris"?

Comment: Yep, (potentially) ancient Greek is [on topic](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358/policy-on-greek-questions) here, and [Gallus](https://ephor.us/epitome/gallus/), after all, was a Roman.

Answer (score 5):

I'm relatively certain it's a demonym derived from [Lycōreia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lycoreia) (Λυκώρεια), a town in Phokis. The suggestion may not be that she was actually from there, but just that she was Greek and Lycoreia is a place in Greece; *Cythēris*, too, is originally a demonym from [Cythēra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kythira) as well as an epithet of Aphrodite.

The etymology of Λυκώρεια itself doesn't seem to be available, but, as pointed out by TKR in the comments, looks a lot like λύκος 'wolf' + ὅρος 'mountain', which makes sense as Lycoreia is supposed to be situated on one of the peaks of the Parnassus mountain range.
(λύκος is not actually the morpheme seen in the suggestions *lykophos* ([λυκόφως](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Dluko%2Ffws)) and *lykauges* ([λυκαυγής](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Dlukaugh%2Fs)); that is *λύκη 'morning twilight', unattested as a simplex word but common in compounds and related to Latin *lūx*.)

The similarity to licorice is certainly coincidental: licorice in Greek was γλυκύρριζα (lit. 'sweet root'), which was borrowed into Latin as *glycyrriza* (spelling varies) and only centuries later became *liquiritia* by contamination with *liquor*, which is the form that ultimately led to English *licorice*.
(The plant genus Lycoris is spider lilies, not licorice, and I suspect it was named after Gallus' *domina*.)

Comment: ὥρα seems unlikely as we'd expect -χ-; maybe rather ὄρος "mountain". And λύκος strikes me as more plausible for the first element, so the placename would be "Wolf Mountain".

Comment: @TKR Oh, I guess Lycoreia spoke Doric, not Aeolic. Yes, that's probably more plausible, then, especially given the terrain.

Comment: Peoples etymology of geographical names by similarities with classical Greek words is considered to produce nonsense, generally.

Comment: @RolandF Only when you do it. Most toponyms in Ancient Greece are Pre-Greek and folk etymology is always a danger, but there is no shortage of genuinely Greek ones.

Comment: Add the impossibility of the Greek speaking people to even make a try to pronounce and transliterate foreign language words from the Pelasgians or Helladian precursors, let alone the barabaricum. I needed a year to get clue of the term 'Γουεστερν' on cinema posters  in Athens. Genuine Greek names of places are a hint for a time of founding after invention of script.

Answer (score -1):

Modern greek [λυκοφως](https://el.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%9B%CF%85%CE%BA%CF%8C%CF%86%CF%89%CF%82) ([wolfs light](https://outils.biblissima.fr/fr/eulexis-web/?lemma=%CE%BB%CF%85%CE%BA%CE%BF%CF%86%CF%89%CF%82&dict=Pape)) is twilight, dawn, dusk. There,too, exists [λυκαυγες](https://el.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%9B%CF%85%CE%BA%CE%B1%CF%85%CE%B3%CE%AD%CF%82) [(Gemoll)](https://outils.biblissima.fr/fr/eulexis-web/?lemma=%CE%BB%CF%85%CE%BA%CE%B1%CF%85%CE%B3%CE%B5%CF%82&dict=Pape), literally light ray (αυγη), still (or again) in use for the early morning dawn.

They had such poetical, religious names like 'εως' and 'Ἀστραῖος'.

Licorice comes from greek γλυκηρηζια (sweet root) [etymonline licorice](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=licorice).

And then there is the last volume of the  saga by Stephenie Mayer

Comment: [λυκόφως is Ancient.](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Dluko%2Ffws) It does not mean "wolf's light".

Comment: The reference from Aelian, a late  Roman writer, reads  (my translation) 'This time of night is called twilight (λυκοφως), when only natural light and shadows remain.
   Homer also teaches me that they say that on a dark night, only wolves go for a walk with their special ability to see.

Comment: The actual translation of those two sentences is more like "Hence that time of night in which only it [i.e. the wolf] has the light provided by nature is called λυκόφως. I also think Homer calls the night in which wolves can see and move about ἀμφιλύκη." (You're confusing, among other things, δοκέω with Latin *doceo*.) Regardless, that's folk etymology; \*λύκη in both of those compounds is related to Latin *lux*, not λύκος.